# Retag [jade] questions

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

There's a bit of a tag collision with [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) for Node.js tags.

Jade for Node.js seems to have gotten the tag wiki seal of approval, so I guess [jade](/questions/tagged/jade) questions should be retagged to something else.

Before I do anything about it, I thought I should ask for guidance, what are the naming conventions in these cases? What about something like [agents-jade](/questions/tagged/agents-jade)?

Comment: The tag wiki uh... doesn't really carry any sort of authority as you seem to believe it does. The wiki is also edited by random member of the community who may or may not be aware of the collision here

Comment: I know the tag wiki isn't a big deal, I was just suggesting that we go with the path of least resistance. I wouldn't want to edit the tag to be about JADE and then spark a turf war with the Jade for Node.js people.